# How to populate social account instance with Facebook data in django-allauth?

Tags: django, facebook, django-allauth

I'm using django-allauth to connect Facebook accounts to users. Everything seemed to work fine except when I inspect the social account object. Under the "extra data" field, all I get is (redacted for privacy): `{"name": "<name>", "id": "<user id>"}`.

By comparison, I get a huge amount of JSON data from Twitter and LinkedIn. I thought I would have gotten a lot more data from Facebook authentication. I've provided my `SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS` settings below. Nothing about it is different from the documentation.

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'facebook': {
        'METHOD': 'oauth2',
        'SCOPE': [
            'email',
            'public_profile',
            'user_friends'
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'
        },
        'FIELDS': [
            'id',
            'email',
            'name',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'verified',
            'locale',
            'timezone',
            'link',
            'gender',
            'updated_time'
        ],
        'EXCHANGE_TOKEN': True,
        'LOCALE_FUNC': lambda request: 'en_US',
        'VERIFIED_EMAIL': True,
        'VERSION': 'v2.4'
    }
}
```

The [documentation does say](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/providers.html#facebook) "After registration you will need to make it available to the public. In order to do that your app first has to be reviewed by Facebook." But it was unclear if registration was required to get more data back while in development.

Should I only get this much data or is there a way to get more? Or is it expected to further query Facebook for data with an access token?

Comment: As has been mentioned a lot of times here already in the last few days and weeks, API v2.4 has changed what fields get returned by default; additional fields now have to be specifically requested. If the framework you are using does not expose the pure API request it makes to you, then you should contact the developers and ask them to update their code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is upgrade to 0.22.0.

https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/1030

https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/1061